# change Global Platform default key set of my Java Card

Tags: javacard, globalplatform

I have finished my applet and I want to use GPShell to change card's default key set to prevent another person replace or delete my applet.

my script to do so is as follows:

```
mode_211
enable_trace
establish_context
enable_trace
card_connect

open_sc -security 1 -keyind 0 -keyver 0 -mac_key 404142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4f -enc_key 404142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4f //  Open secure channel
put_sc_key -keyver 1 -newkeyver 1 -mac_key 404142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4e -enc_key 404142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4e -kek_key 404142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4e -cur_kek 404142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4f

card_disconnect
release_context
```

but when I try this script, GPShell returns me the following error:

```
mode_211
enable_trace
establish_context
enable_trace
card_connect
open_sc -security 1 -keyind 0 -keyver 0 -mac_key 404142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4f -enc_key 404142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4f // Open secure channel
Command --> 80CA006600
Wrapped command --> 80CA006600
Response <-- 664C734A06072A864886FC6B01600C060A2A864886FC6B02020101630906072A864886FC6B03640B06092A864886FC6B040215650B06092B8510864864020103660C060A2B060104012A026E01029000
Command --> 80500000089AA60E4925924D6900
Wrapped command --> 80500000089AA60E4925924D6900
Response <-- 000011370001AB741C0BFF02047E4413D6E4873750AB69F325A1E4FF9000
Command --> 848201001056D480DA94FF6A33778F6D68A7497C8C
Wrapped command --> 848201001056D480DA94FF6A33778F6D68A7497C8C
Response <-- 9000
put_sc_key -keyver 1 -newkeyver 1 -mac_key 404142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4e -enc_key 404142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4e -kek_key 404142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4e -cur_kek 404142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4f
Error: unknown option -cur_kek
```

can anyone help to solve the problem? is any of my options wrong? can you write me the correct script for GPShell?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `unknown option -cur_kek` seems to be quite clear...

Comment: @vojta it's true that GPShell supports this option!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `-current_kek` instead of `-cur_kek` as there seems to be a typo in [the gpshell documentation](http://sourceforge.net/p/globalplatform/wiki/GPShell/#key-commands).

The relevant part of the source code is [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/globalplatform/code/462/tree/trunk/gpshell/src/gpshell.c#l458).